# A question on normal probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I read someplace that the area under the normal probability distribution curve evaluated between either side of the mean to one standard deviation is constant and equal to 68.3%. I tried to derive it multiple times by integrating the probability density formula but it somehow is too difficult to evaluate analytically. Please give some insight on how this fact is derived. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The analytical computation just makes use of the Taylor expansion, which is not difficult to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to calculate is

$$P(\mu-\sigma<X<\mu+\sigma)$$

Now standardize $X$ by variable's change

$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma }\sim N(0;1)$$

Obtaining

$$P(-1<Z<1)=\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)=0.8413-0.1587=0.6826$$

The values of $\Phi(z)=\int_{-\infty}^z \phi(t)dt$ are tabulated in Standard Gaussian table

Comment: @how can we calculate the value of the CDF? Can we do it without a computer?

Comment: Computer, paper tables or numerical integration

Comment: @AmbicaGovind : FYK here https://onlinepubs.trb.org/onlinepubs/nchrp/cd-22/manual/v2appendixc.pdf you can find an example of Paper Statistical Tables

Comment: thanks very much!